# Most python(3)esque way to repeatedly SELECT from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a csv file of customer ids (`CRM_id`). I need to get their primary keys (an autoincrement int) from the customers table of the database. (I can't be assured of the integrity of the `CRM_id`s so I chose not to make that the primary key).

So:

```
customers = []
with open("CRM_ids.csv", 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    customerfile = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
    #only one "CRM_id" field per row
    customers = [c for c in customerfile]
```

So far so good? I think this is the most pythonesque way of doing that (but happy to hear otherwise).

Now comes the ugly code. It works, but I hate appending to the list because that has to copy and reallocate memory for each loop, right? Is there a better way (pre-allocate + enumerate to keep track of the index comes to mind, but maybe there's an even quickler/better way by being clever with the SQL so as not to do several thousand separate queries...)?

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='me', password=sys.argv[1], host="localhost", database="mydb")
cursor = cnx.cursor()
select_customer = ("SELECT id FROM customers WHERE CRM_id = %(CRM_id)s LIMIT 1;")
c_ids = []
for row in customers:
    cursor.execute(select_customer, row)
    #note fetchone() returns a tuple, but the SELECTed set
    #only has a single column so we need to get this column with the [0]
    c_ids.extend(cursor.fetchall())
    c_ids = [c[0] for c in c_ids]
```

Edit:
Purpose is to get the primary keys in a list so I can use these to allocate some other data from other CSV files in linked tables (the customer id primary key is a foreign key to these other tables, and the allocation algorithm changes, so it's best to have the flexibility to do the allocation in python rather than hard coding SQL queries). I know this sounds a little backwards, but the "client" only works with spreadsheets rather than an ERP/PLM, so I have to build the "relations" for this small app myself.

Comment: The word you're looking for is 'pythonic'.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  it appears that you moved data into a database, and are now trying to attach the new rowid to the old data in the csv file.  What is the end goal?

Comment: Will a cross reference listing generated with `select id, CRM_id from customers` fulfill your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about changing your query to get what you want?

```
crm_ids = ",".join(customers)
select_customer = "SELECT UNIQUE id FROM customers WHERE CRM_id IN (%s);" % crm_ids
```

MySQL should be fine with even a multi-megabyte query, according to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html); if it gets to be a *really* long list, you can always break it up - two or three queries is guaranteed much faster than a few thousand.

Comment: Ah great, that looks right. Except, shouldn't I `ORDER BY FIELD` to ensure I get the `id`s back in the same order as the `CRM_id`s are passed?

Comment: Also, it's possible to use `str.format()` instead of `%` from 2.6 I believe. (More of a reminder to me when I reread this later for use in a more generalised case)

Comment: Finally, if `CRM_id` is a `VARCHAR` it would probably be necessary to `"\",\"".join(customers` and then `CRM_ids = "\"" + CRM_ids + "\""` to wrap each field in quotes as a string.

Comment: If you need to access via `CRM_id`, I'd just `SELECT` that field as well - then each row returned will have the `CRM_id` as well as the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

how about storing your csv in a dict instead of a list:

```
customers = [c for c in customerfile]
```

becomes:

```
customers = {c['CRM_id']:c for c in customerfile}
```

then select the entire xref:

```
result = cursor.execute('select id, CRM_id from customers')
```

and add the new rowid as a new entry in the dict:

```
for row in result:
    customers[row[1]]['newid']=row[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's not what I need to do for the moment, but it will be useful when I restructure the code later. Sorry, I should have been clearer with the question.